Event loop already running when unit testing
I'm running into an issue when running a unit test. I'll try my best to explain the problem.
Big picture there are 3 files:

unit_test.py
main.py
helper.py (async code)

When I run the unit test, it calls the run function in main.py, and the code fails on loop.run_until_complete(...) due to a
RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running

Note: There are other files using main.py that I have no control of and making main.py async would break a lot of things.
unit_test.py
  class TestCode(TestCase):
    def test_func(self) -> None:
        outp = MainClass().run() # runs the function inside main.py 

main.py
class MainClass():

    def run():
     loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
     asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
   
     results = loop.run_until_complete(# calls an async function in helper.py)


Please edit your question to include a minimum reproducible example with test data demonstrating your problem.
